# how to write a script or shell command to use a regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, bash, shell

i am an enthusiast of computers but never studied programming.

i am trying to learn Perl, because i found it interesting since i learned to use a little bit of regular expressions with Perl flavor, cause i needed to replace words in certain parts of the strings and that's how i found perl.

but i don't know anything about programming, i would like to know simple examples how to use regular expression from the shell (terminal) or basic scripts.

for example if i have in a folder a text document called : input.txt
how can i perform the following regex.

text to match :

```
text text text
text text text
```

what i want : change the second occurrence of the word text for the word: changed

```
(\A.*?tex.*?)text(.*?)$
```

replace for : `\1changed\3`

expected result:

```
text changed text
text changed text
```

using a text editor that would be using Multi-line and global modifiers.
now, how can i process this from the shell. 
CD path  and then what?
or a script? what should contain to make it workable.

please consider i don't know anything about Perl, but only about its regexp syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression part is easy.

```
 s/\btext\b.*?\K\btext\b/changed/;
```

However, how to apply it if you're learning perl... that's the hard part.  One could demonstrate a one liner, but that's not that helpful.

```
perl -i -pe 's/\btext\b.*?\K\btext\b/changed/;' file.txt
```

So instead, I'd recommend looking at [`perlfaq5 #How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f).  Ultimately what you need to learn is how to open a file for reading, and iterate over the lines.  And alternatively, how to open a file for writing.  With these two tools, you can do a lot.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'blah.txt';
my $newfile = 'new_blah.txt';

open my $infh, '<', $file;
open my $outfh, '>', $newfile;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    # Any manipulation to $line here, such as that regex:
    # $line =~ s/\btext\b.*?\K\btext\b/changed/;

    print $outfh $line;
}

close $infh;
close $outfh;
```

**Update to explain regex**

```
s{
    \btext\b      # Find the first 'text' not embedded in another word
    .*?           # Non-greedily skip characters
    \K            # Keep the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in replacement
    \btext\b      # Match 2nd 'text' not embedded in another word
}{changed}x;      # Replace with 'changed'  /x modifier to allow whitespace in LHS.
```

Comment: trying to learn Perl is hard, the link you provided seems as it is assumed people have previous knowledge on Perl.  thanks for the answer. why do you use boundaries? is ^ or \A and $ or \r\n consider as word boundaries as well?

Comment: Ultimately, your knowledge of a programming language is only going to be good as the quality of your reference material and how well you're familiar with it.  Honestly, there are too many details and edge cases for most people to remember everything about a language, so it's actually MUCH more important that one knows where to look for information.

Comment: I'd suggest getting a [`learning perl`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) or [`programming perl`](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) book, and take that formal approach.  Eventually, you will become more familiar with [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/) and know where to look there, but I agree that it's not as good for the beginner.  Perhaps someone else will suggest another resource.

Comment: thanks, i pasted the regexp on the script and i named it 1.pl and runt it but returns this:  i added this : while (my $line = 's/\btext\b.*?\K\btext\b/changed/;' <$infh>) {     and returns : syntax error at 1.pl line 11, near "$infh>"
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at 1.pl line 14.
Execution of 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: i have a document call input and the script as 1.pl using the shell gave me that result, can you help me please?

Comment: I've updated the original example code to show where to include the regex.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50825/discussion-between-miller-and-alex)

Comment: Hi Miller, the original question `\1changed\3` was easy for me to understand; while I had a hard time trying to understand your answer, as this is the first time I saw the usage of `\K`. So let me ask this way, if the input text is `beg whatever end`, and I need to change it with `\1changed\3` to `beg changed end`, would the way you do matching (ie the usage of `\K`) need to be change as well please? thx